# I declared--> str1="bbccaa". I want result to be all the b's and a's i.e 'bbaa',however

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently practicing regex. I declared--> `str1="bbccaa"`. I want result to be all the b's and a's i.e 'bbaa'. I tried-> '[^c]+' ,[ab]+ But everything I tried ultimately gave an output as 'bb'. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong and also the solution, please??

Comment: `s = s.replace('c', '')`? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Or replace with an empty string matching not a or b `[^ab]+`

Comment: i declared str1="bbccaa", I wanted an output which gives an output of everything except the 'c' i.e an output which is "bbaa". How do i write a regex which gives me this output?? I tried using -->[^c]+  and [ab]+. But these werent giving me desired outputs. They gave me only "bb".

Comment: Except the `cc` - `re.sub(cc, replace_with_this, string_to_process)`

Comment: Ah thanks. But is there an expression i could write inside of re.search or re.match that could give me this same output?

Comment: So, the only problem was that you found a single match only with `re.search`. Use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` to match all the matches.

Comment: You declare? Does that mean you're using it as the target string for a regular expression ?  New regex students usually aren't into the details of matching different parts of a string, but since you stipulate `[ab]+` I have to assume you understand capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

s = "bbccaa"
print(re.sub("[^ab]+", r"", s))
#bbaa
```

Comment: Ah thanks. But is there an expression i could write inside of re.search or re.match that could give me this same output?

Comment: You would need to use `re.findall` to return multiple matches...

Comment: okay, got it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are practicing here, another expression, not the best one, would be:

```
([ab]+)|(.+?)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QN7RIz/1/)

Comment: re.search(([ab]+)|(.*?),str1)<-- did this. But im still getting --> 'bb'

Comment: A little advice, never put `.*?` as the last construct in a regex. It will never, ever match a character. Therefore group 2 will always either be _NULL_ or the _empty_ string.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.findall` for that, then `join` results following way:

```
import re
str1="bbccaa"
output = ''.join(re.findall('a|b',str1))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
bbaa
```

I do not see way to make it solely with `re` (without `join`)